# Display messages

Tags: apex

[image: Dislay message]

Hi,

I would like to know is there some other way to display messages in Salesforce.

I am using the addError() method but it is not very effective as you can see in the image.

I am trying to display message 'The merchant alredy exist' in a Salesforce page but addError() is not an option for me and I am searching for a better method or option to display messages in Salesforce.

Please advise if there is a better way to display messages in Salesforce.

Comment: http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2012/08/the-importance-of-page-messages.html

Comment: This is pretty much standard way to go. What exactly is the problem? Do you want the error to appear under the corresponding field? Or you want the styling of the message to be different?

Comment: The duplicate lines are typically related to using apexPages.addMessage() when catching a DML exception - because the DML exception is already in the VF context.  I've written handlers in my catch blocks to avoid this